# how to parse json data and display in listview using aysnctask

Tags: android, json, listview, android-studio

I am parsing data and displaying it in `ListView`. I am done with my parsing successfully but I can't display that parsed data in `ListView`. I don't know what error I am getting. It automatically comes to home screen and I cant see even the error. I want to display the datas in `ListView`, those datas which I added in my `HashMap`.

```
     private class Getiingbusdetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private static String url="http://runtowin.in/v2/ap/route_api.php?apicode=runtowin002&dateOfJourney=2017-01-01&originId=8&destinationId=5";

            String response = " ";
            String jsonstr;
            ProgressDialog dialogProgress = new ProgressDialog(Searchbus.this);
            AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

            JSONArray array3;
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                dialogProgress.setCancelable(true);
                dialogProgress.setMessage("Please wait..");
                dialogProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
                dialogProgress.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                try {
                    response = mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
                Log.i("url", "" + url);
                Log.i("routes", "" + response);
                jsonstr = response;

                if (jsonstr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray(jsonstr);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj1 = array1.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray array2 = obj1.getJSONArray("bus_schedule");
                            for (int j = 0; j < array2.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject obj2 = array2.getJSONObject(j);
                                 array3 = obj2.getJSONArray("bus_route");

                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

                                    for (int k = 0; k < array3.length(); k++) {
                                    JSONObject obj3 = array3.getJSONObject(k);

                                    String s1 = obj3.getString("serviceDate");
                                    String s2 = obj3.getString("amenities");
                                    String s3 = obj3.getString("startCityName");
                                    String s44 = obj3.getString("departureTime");
                                    String s4=dateformatter(s44);
                                    String s5 = obj3.getString("fare");
                                    String s6 = obj3.getString("endCityName");
                                    String s77 = obj3.getString("arrivalTime");
                                    String s7=dateformatter(s77);


                                    String s8 = obj3.getString("operatorName");
                                    String s9 = obj3.getString("bus_id");
                                    String s10 = obj3.getString("journeyHours");
                                    String s11 = obj3.getString("available_seat");
                                    String s12 = obj3.getString("total_seats");
                                    String s13 = obj3.getString("seat_type");
                                    String s14 = (""+s4+" - "+""+s7);
                                    Log.e("servicedate"+s1,"amenities"+s2+"startcityname"+s3);
                                   map.put(SERVICEDATE,s1);
                                    map.put(AMENITIES,s2);
                                    map.put(DEPARTTIME,s4);
                                    map.put(FARE,s5);
                                    map.put(ARRIVALTIME,s7);
                                    map.put(JOURNEYHOURS,s10);
                                    map.put(SEATSAVAILABLE,s12);
                                    map.put(TOTALTIMING,s14);

                                    busdetails.add(map);
   }

                                JSONArray array4 = obj2.getJSONArray("boardingPoint");

                               for (int l = 0; l < array4.length(); l++) {
                                    JSONObject obj4 = array4.getJSONObject(l);

                                    String s14 = obj4.getString("boardingPointName");
                                    String s15 = obj4.getString("boardingPointContact");
                                    String s16 = obj4.getString("boardingPointTime");
                                    String s17 = obj4.getString("boardingPointId");
                                    String s18 = obj4.getString("BusId");

                                }

                            }

                        }

                        Log.e("response", array1.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

                    }

                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

                try {
    /*
                    if (array3.equals("Bus not available.")) {
    */
                    dialogProgress.dismiss();
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Searchbus.this, busdetails, R.layout.busdetailslistview,
                                new String[]{TOTALTIMING, FARE, JOURNEYHOURS, SEATSAVAILABLE, AMENITIES, DEPARTTIME},
                                new int[]{R.id.bustiming, R.id.fare_amt, R.id.journey_hours, R.id.seats_avail, R.id.busnametpe, R.id.bustype, R.id.bt_viewseat});
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    Toast.makeText(Searchbus.this, "" + journeydatefromjson + ".." + busname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }`
my layout is `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_searchbus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.notebook.runtowin.Searchbus">

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mytoolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="3sp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/datelayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18sp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dateview"
            android:hint="date"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datelayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Operator &amp; Departure"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/departtextview"
   android:padding="5sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/departtextview" />


    </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/listviewbusdetails"
                android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:dividerHeight="1sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/from_to"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
` my listview code is `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/busname"
        android:padding="4sp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/no_bus"
            android:text="no bus is available"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="nddnsadasndman"
            android:id="@+id/bustiming"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bustype"
            android:padding="4sp"
            android:id="@+id/busnametpe"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="busslepper"
            android:id="@+id/bustype"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="450"
    android:id="@+id/fare_amt"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="15sp"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="duration"
            android:id="@+id/journey_hours"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/seats"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View seats"
            android:layout_margin="8sp"
            android:id="@+id/bt_viewseat"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="seats"
            android:id="@+id/seats_avail"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>`

my logcat error is `12-29 14:53:35.435 13421-13421/com.example.notebook.runtowin W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-29 14:53:35.647 13421-13421/com.example.notebook.runtowin I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
12-29 14:53:35.651 13421-13421/com.example.notebook.runtowin I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
12-29 14:53:35.666 13421-13421/com.example.notebook.runtowin I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: org.apache.http.impl.conn.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
12-29 14:53:35.692 13421-13459/com.example.notebook.runtowin D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-29 14:53:35.708 13421-13460/com.example.notebook.runtowin W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/com.qualcomm.qti.GBAHttpAuthentication.jar
12-29 14:53:35.742 13421-13421/com.example.notebook.runtowin D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
12-29 14:53:35.774 13421-13459/com.example.notebook.runtowin I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : a7823f5, I59a6815413
                                                                       Build Date                       : 09/23/16
                                                                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.07.00.00
                                                                       Local Branch                     : mybranch22028469
                                                                       Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.3.3_rb2.26
                                                                       Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                       Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
12-29 14:53:35.784 13421-13459/com.example.notebook.runtowin I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-29 14:53:35.848 13421-13459/com.example.notebook.runtowin E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
12-29 14:53:35.848 13421-13459/com.example.notebook.runtowin E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
12-29 14:53:37.589 13421-13460/com.example.notebook.runtowin I/city: [{"cityId":"5","cityName":"Coimbatore"},{"cityId":"6","cityName":"Chennai"},{"cityId":"7","cityName":"Madurai"},{"cityId":"8","cityName":"Kanyakumari"},{"cityId":"9","cityName":"Nagercoil"},{"cityId":"12","cityName":"Anjugramam"},{"cityId":"11","cityName":"Erode"},{"cityId":"13","cityName":"Valliyur"},{"cityId":"14","cityName":"Kavalkinaru"},{"cityId":"15","cityName":"Tirunelveli"}]
12-29 14:53:37.606 13421-13421/com.example.notebook.runtowin I/InstituteName: [Coimbatore, 5, Chennai, 6, Madurai, 7, Kanyakumari, 8, Nagercoil, 9, Anjugramam, 12, Erode, 11, Valliyur, 13, Kavalkinaru, 14, Tirunelveli, 15]
`
```

Comment: Already doing same. what problem getting with current code?

Comment: use logcat to see errors, warnings etc. and find your error. than prepare your question again.

Comment: post error log or stacktrace

Comment: Please use better names for your variables..

Comment: when i go this activit,a progress bar is loading and then it automatically comes to previous activity.i dont see any errors in logcat.i debuged and find that its working fine until postexecute executes.when postexecute comes it automatically comes to new activity

Comment: @akash...sry for inconvenience..i m new to android.this is the task given to me from my office.i m n hurry to finish it thats y i cant code properly...nxt time i will rectify it

Comment: any help please

Comment: When you create the adapter, I found you have 6 items in String[] but 7 items in int[]. Hope that help!

Comment: @I_A_mok thankyou...u are correct..now list is displaying.bt it showing only TOTALTIMING IN ALL TEXTVIEWS .can u suugests any link how to use this same with customadapter instead of simple adapter

Comment: You created a SimpleAdapter and assign it to ListAdapter. I never try this and that may be the cause of your problem. Try to make both SimpleAdapter and I think it will work. Otherwise log your data and see if they are correct. If data is OK, then update the code in the post and may be I can find the error. I am just writing a blog about ListView: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.hk/. If you are new on ListView, that may help.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you parse the json correctly. System.out.pritnln("text") and Log.d("some", "thing") are your friends.

2) In Android Studio there is an easy way to view the log, look for: 6: Android Monitor.

3) Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view) excellent post about ListView and it's Adapters. Mock your data &| classes to make sure you get the input you want.

4) Building Android Apps in a hurry is a bad idea. Java / Android is not strong with fast building, Cordova / Javascript / HTML are better for that. But Java & Android have the power and speed when done right...